# How do i put multiple vectors into a matrix r?

Tags: r

I have a list of 10 vectors that are in the form of the following:

```
 x2 <- c(261,235,316,299,220,195,158,132,159,141)
 x3 <- c(601,489,549,594,593,503,387,403,439,375)
```

How do i combine all these vectors into a matrix? without having to type x2,x3,x4 etc into rbind().

How do i put multiple vectors into a matrix r?

Answer (score 3):

```
do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("x", 2:3)))
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#x2  261  235  316  299  220  195  158  132  159   141
#x3  601  489  549  594  593  503  387  403  439   375
```